# Авторизация на php, mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

Перечитала кучу сайтов, книжек, все, что нашла по поводу работы PHPSESSID, сессий и т.п. **Какая задача стоит?** Представьте 1 и ту же страничку (личный профиль). На нее могут зайти пользователи - владелец и не владелец. Владелец должен увидеть возможность редактирования, а не владелец должен увидеть просто страничку без возможности редактирования. Что у меня есть? При авторизации, запускается сессия, хранящая логин, почту, пароль и все столбцы записи из БД, именно по этому пользователю, а еще я знаю ID сессии.

**ТАк вот и подходим к сути:** за что мне зацепиться, чтобы страница отображалась по-разному у 2ух людей (один создатель страницы - другой не создатель)? Как мне сравнивать сессии, если я только  1 создавала...

*Вообще, приветствуются любые велосипеды и длинные коды, я буду рада любой помощи и не помощи. Я не использую PDO или CMS, пока только рукописный код на html, css, php, mysql.*

Comment: пдо - это не отдельный язык)) это банальный набор функций

Comment: *за что мне зацепиться* Пользователи - они авторизуются (а до того или без того они все анонимы). Вот за неё, родимую, и цепляйтесь - насколько совпадает то, кем авторизовался, с тем, чья страница.

Comment: А без авторизации я их вообще на сайт не пускаю, вот я жестокая , да. Это как бы, ну вот факт

Comment: @Akina, ну а что-нибудь еще подскажете? Я вроде бы все переменные имею, что нужны, а как их связать то?

Comment: Да  понятия не имею. Для меня что PHP, что HTML, что сессии и куки разные - всё одно тёмный лес, ибо не нужно... есть, и ладно. Но народ использует - и у Вас получится.

Comment: @Jean-Claude, ну ошиблась от незнания. Подскажете что-нибудь?

Comment: создайте роли пользователей, при авторизации проверить кто это, админ или юзер, и соответственно вывести одному одно, второму другое

Comment: @ВикторияБлагодер >создайте роли пользователей - имеется в виду к таблице со всеми пользователями добавить еще одну колонку, в которой будет находиться например 0 или 1. И 0 будет задаваться обычным пользователям, 1 - админу. И перед авторизацией делаете запрос на проверку, 0 там или 1, чтобы определить админ логинится или нет

Comment: Это будет работать так, что 1 пользователь может быть админом 1 страницы и юзером другой?

Comment: Вот развели как всегда турусы на колесах. Роли, рояли, оркестр блин с подтанцовками. Когда здесь нужно **ровно одно условие** `if($_SESSION['user_id'] === $_GET['id'])` значит хозяин, может редактировать

Comment: @ВикторияБлагодер , это будет работать так, что если в данной колонке значение "1" - это админ. Если значение "0" - обычный пользователь. А там уже дальше сами решаете, что отображать для админа, а что для обычного пользователя.

Comment: @Ипатьев, и мне это условие надо встроить в код страницы пользователя? Встроить так, что бы потом по схеме if и else выводить 2 разных страницы?

Comment: ну или две разных страницы, но обычно просто добавляют это условие к кнопкам редактирования и их обработке. но для простоты можно для начала две разных

Comment: @Ипатьев, тут неувязочка в том, что у меня на странице пользователя я из сессии достаю его данные (из бд) и вывожу через сам php код. Откуда берется параметр $_GET ? Ну и кроме того, косяки с кавычками идут, ведь если выводить как тело цикла if, то там html код будет сам в кавычках, а его разрывы, чтоб вывести из сессии данные (о чем в 1ой части говорила), тоже в кавычках, и поэтому не хочет весь код встраиваться

Comment: 1. как заходят другие пользователи на страницу? откуда, по какой ссылке?

Comment: 2. Это всё ОЧЕНЬ [просто делается](https://phpize.online/?phpses=65ebbd78fe85da1b286bf9e81c933f15)

Comment: 1) Авторизованный пользователь заходит на чужую страницу просто рандомно из списка возможных (я их просто вывела из БД). И тут нужно решать, показывать ли ему страницу с возможностью редактировать (ну только, если он ее и создал), либо он гость на ней и может только смотреть что-то.
2) Нуууу, я так поняла, в примере по ссылке Вы к каждой кнопке редактирования писали эту проверку. Но, можно ли как-то, чтоб вся страничка либо с редактированием, либо без отображалась? 
*Ну я понимаю, что надоела, но не понимаю*

Comment: ЧТО ЗА СПИСОК? ЧТО "вывела из бд"? ПО КАКОЙ ССЫЛКЕ переходит? Как страница профиля понимает, чей это профиль?

Comment: Под "списком" я подразумеваю записи в БД. Ну 1 запись содержит всю информацию про пользователя, я и вывела их все разом, после каждого добавила ссылку на одну единственную страницу профиля. То есть со страницы users пользователь тыкает на ссылку и попадает на страницу profile, которую и надо представлять по-разному. 
Как страница понимает, чей профиль. Ну, человек авторизовывается, попадает на profile, оттуда переходит на users, а с этой страницы и тыкает на другого пользователя, попадая на profile (но уже другой, не тот, что после авторизации). Так как-то...

Comment: ЧТО В ССЫЛКЕ? можно не многоречиво рассказывать про страницы, а ПРОСТО ответить на прямой вопрос, **как выглядит ссылка**  по которой переходят на страницу профиля?

Comment: ```<a href='profile.php'>  ``` Вот так :)

Comment: такая ссылка не может показывать профили разных пользователей.

Comment: Что мне в ней поменять? У меня есть id сессии только что авторизованного пользователя. С ней как-то работать?

Comment: надо забыть про сессии и авторизацию. купить книжку по пхп, Котерова. И потихоньку осваивать. В частности передачу переменных в адресной строке. В таблице пользователей в БД хотя бы есть id?

Comment: В таблице есть id, да. И я его записывала в сессию, когда пользователь авторизовывался

Comment: еще раз повторяю. **надо забыть про сессии**. Сначала надо научиться отображать страницу профиля.

Comment: ссылка должна выглядеть вот так `<a href='profile.php?id=666'>`

Comment: Ну я же не должна писать каждую ссылку от руки? Они как-то сами строятся, как мне казалось

Comment: вот при построении и надо id добавлять. для каждого пользователя

Comment: Небольшое отступление: в книжке Котлярова я найду применение этого? Книжка 2016, я только такую нашла

Comment: КотЕрова. Да, там все это объясняется. И как ХТМЛ выводить, и как ссылки делать,и как с сессиями работать. Без учебника вообще нельзя программированием заниматься

Comment: У меня книги Дронов и Прохоренок набор 4е издание 2017 и просто Дронов пхп и майскюэль 2021. Но в них очень печально это все описано

Comment: @Ипатьев, а можно для очень тупых попросить ткнуть пальцем страницы, где описана передача в ссылке id ? Это $_GET ?

Comment: да, это  $_GET. но скакать по страницам не стоит. учить нужно всё. программирование - это не вязание крючком, его невозможно освоить за вечер по  журналу Бурда

Comment: Спасибо большое